# When using a 32-bit register to address memory in the real mode, contents of the register must never exceed 0000FFFFH. Why?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, real-mode

I have found this in the book "THE INTEL MICROPROCESSORS" of Barry B. Brey. Is it true? But why? I know that in the real mode of actual 8086 microprocessor, there is no 32 bit register. So the same restriction should be imposed on 32 bit registers now?

Comment: What is real mode? Do you know?

Comment: On a 32-bit processor (386+) you can use 32-bit registers and 32-bit addressing in real mode. The address can be above 0xFFFF if you are in [unreal mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode). In traditional real mode you are limited to a limit of 0xFFFF.

Comment: This is already the second misleading thing in that book, is it actually any good?

Answer (score 5):

I would say that the contents of the register is irrelevant; the effective address must not exceed 0xFFFF:

- If `EBP` has the value 0xFFFFFFF0 and you use the instruction `mov EBX, [EBP+0x20]` you access memory at the address 0x10. This should work perfectly although the register's value is above 0xFFFF.
- If `EBP` has the value 0xFFF0 and you use the same instruction you access memory at 0x10010. This should not work although the register has a value below 0xFFFF.

Michael Pech already gave a hint for the reason in his comment:

Memory segments do have a segment limit in real mode!

In real mode a segment limit check is not desired. The developers of the 286 could have developed the circuit in a way that segment limit checking is switched off in real mode. This would have made the circuit more complex and expensive. So they decided to simply initialize the segment limit to 0xFFFF which de-facto disables segment limit checking although segment limit checking is switched on.

In the 386 Intel obviously did not change this initialization value from 0xFFFF to 0xFFFFFFFF.

On the 386 you are able to change this limit using the "unreal mode" mentioned in Michael Petch'es comment. However as far as I know no official document of Intel says that this method is "officially" allowed - which means that no document is saying that this method will work with all future Intel CPUs.

In the "virtual mode" of the 386+ for example (this mode is used to run real mode programs while a protected mode OS is active) the limits are fixed to 0xFFFF.